# how to use IIS redirect to send requests to node in another port

Tags: node.js, redirect, iis, proxy, windows-server-2008

I am using windows server 2008 R2 standard and I have installed a node.js app that runs fine in port 3000.

In windows server, the admin used ISS to create a Default Web Site , so the port 80 is open to everyone. This works fine, I go to mywebsite.com and I get the ISS7 logo.

I cannot run the node app directly on port 80. I have to use a proxy to send traffic from mywebsite.com:80 to localhost:3000. (is it localhost? I guess it is)

I try to do this by using Application Request Routing. According to this [tutorial](http://www.gitshah.com/2013/06/how-to-use-iis7-as-front-end-to-java.html)

I install ARR and create a new server farm named "redirect".

I put windows server IP as the server address, click advanced settings, click applicationRequestRout, change httpPort to 3000 (my node app) and hit Finish

So now the server farm named redirect represents my node on port 3000 , right?

I go to server farms > redirect > servers, double click on the one server on the list and hit Connect to the server

Click URL rewrite, Add Rule, Blank Rule under Inbound Rules

I name it "redirecctrule", pick "Wildcards" under Using and then hit Test pattern.

I put `/*` in Input data to test and `/*` in pattern (wildcard), so everything that comes from mywebsite.com can go to node , port 3000, right? Maybe here is my mistake? I dont know.

Then I hit Test, the test is ok, so I close and hit Yes to Save that rule. I also pick "Route to server farm" under Action and hit Apply on the right.

Node is running. If I go to mywebsite.com on my browser, I still get the ISS logo, not the website from node. I restarted the server and tried again, still nothing.

What am I missing here? How can I redirect traffic from ISS Web Site port 80 to node app, port 3000?

Any advice would be great, I am trying all day and it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: Go over some typical mistakes might help https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the tip. I managed to create a rule that works. But now if I type mywebsite.com  in my address bar, it turns to localhost:3000 and I dont want that. Also , it gives an error that I cannot access this site anyway. So what should I do? Any advice? Should I deploy a proxy in that IIS7 site? Thanks

Comment: you are redirecting instead of rewriting right now. You need to change that and use ARR proxy mode.

Comment: @LexLi True. I found some tutorials and I am ready to try. Quick question, please. I started creating a reverse proxy then Canceled to Remove the URL rewrite rule that I created. I was planning to start a new proxy after that. I removed the url rewrite rule. All the lists are empty. I refreshed and even restarted the server. But , still I write mywebsite.com and it still goes to localhost:3000 . WTF? Any ideas? Why the rewrite rule is still in effect? What am I missing? Thanks again

Comment: Refresh your browser cache, as it can simply remember the previous redirection.

Comment: @LexLi Ah thanks, that was it. Thanks. Ok, I will try the tutorials and let you know

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the help, I managed to easily set a reverse proxy using [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/) tutorial. But now I have another problem. If you have any free time, please check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520869/cannot-get-data-from-node-app-via-iss-reverse-proxy). Thanks